xAI Error: API request failed: Unprocessable Entity
I'm trying to use the new xAI API but I'm getting this error:

Error: API request failed: Unprocessable Entity

I am making a request to the /v1/chat/completions endpoint with the following messages:
cleaned messages: [
  {
    "role": "user",
    "content": "Hello"
  }
]

My entire NextJS route:
export async function POST(req: NextRequest) {
  try {
    const body = await req.json();
    const rawMessages = body.messages;

    const messages = rawMessages.map((msg: any) => ({
        ...msg,
        content: typeof msg.content === 'string' ? cleanBOM(msg.content) : msg.content
      }));
      
      console.log('cleaned messages:', JSON.stringify(messages, null, 2));
      

    const response = await fetch('https://api.x.ai/v1/chat/completions', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${process.env.XAI_API_KEY}`
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        messages,
        model: 'grok-beta',
      })
    });

    console.log('response:', JSON.stringify(response.body)
    );
    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error(`API request failed: ${response.statusText}`);
    }

    const data: ChatResponse = await response.json();
    
    return NextResponse.json(data);

  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error processing chat request:', error);
    return NextResponse.json(
      { error: 'Failed to process chat request' },
      { status: 500 }
    );
  }
}


I couldn't get the API to work using a direct POST request but the xAI API is directly compatible with the OpenAI SDK so you can literally swap out the baseUrl and apiKey properties on the OpenAI client and use it the same way you would all of the OpenAI models:
import OpenAI from "openai";
const openai = new OpenAI({
apiKey: process.env.XAI_API_KEY,  
baseURL: "https://api.x.ai/v1",
});

const completion = await openai.chat.completions.create({
  model: "grok-beta",
  messages: [
    { role: "system", content: "You are Grok, a chatbot inspired by the Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy." },
    {
      role: "user",
      content: "What is the meaning of life, the universe, and everything?",
    },
  ],
});

console.log(completion.choices[0].message);


